# UDS with more than eight bytes

Tags: protocol, can

The unified diagnostic services (UDS) protocol in [ISO 15765-4](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=46045) seems to be specifically designed for bus systems with a message length of eight bytes (for example, [CAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus)). Now, new transport layers like [FlexRay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlexRay) support messages with more than eight bytes.

Is it possible to adapt UDS for those layers? If so, how? Is there a planned update for that standard?

Comment: Bruno, I rolled back your tag edit. The Flexray tag didn't exist yet, and it's unlikely that it will be used in other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible and called Transport Protocol which basically splits messages with more than eight bytes into multiple messages.

Look at part 2 of this particular standard  which describes this.

There is also something called CAN FD (Flexible Data Rate). Which will send one message containing more bytes (so not splitting them). But this is rather limited by the hardware than the software layers.

Answer (score 0):

UDS also has ISO Standard for FlexRay implementation (earliest I know is from 2010): 
**ISO 10681-2** (for Transport and Network layer)
**ISO 14229 1-2** is for Session/Application layer.